# How can I show an animated spinner while cloning a git repository and show the live output of the clone command in Golang?

Tags: git, go, command-line-interface, stdout

I am creating a project management CLI tool to help me organize my projects and format them. I am trying to use go-git to clone a remote repository (in the future I plan for this to be fetched from a config file, but for now I hardcoded a repository) to a specified directory. While cloning this repository, I want to be able to display an animated spinner above, and the output of the clone function below it. A simple example of how I would want it to look:

```
⠸ Cloning Remote
Enumerating objects: 13122, done.
Counting objects: 100% (66/66), done.
Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
```

Where the top spinner part would constantly update while the bottom would be a live output of the cloning command. I have tried setting the message of the spinner, but git.PlainClone's output needs a Write() function. I am using yacspin (github.com/theckman/yacspin) for the animated spinners, and I am really not sure where to go.

I am new to Golang so I am not sure exactly how to do things yet! Thanks for the help!

The code I am using to clone a generic repository:

```golang
_, err := git.PlainClone("./clone/", false, &git.CloneOptions{
    URL:      "https://github.com/go-git/go-git",
    Progress: os.Stdout,
})
```

I tried creating a io.Writer custom thing, but I am not sure how to do that exactly. I have found some articles, but none have helped me understand this problem. The solution I would try and achieve is have the message at the beginning, then every time the write function is called, append a newline followed by the contents of that message, which in the writer function, is an array of bytes.

I am new to Golang so I am not sure exactly how to do things yet! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right path trying to create an `io.Writer`, but things get kind of messy because the git output contains terminal control codes to move the cursor around. You can inspect the output from git just a bit to find newlines and control codes to move the cursor up one line and then use these to modify the message you set the spinner to display to include the appropriate number of lines:

```golang
// Implements io.Writer; changes the spinner's message to match whatever
// is sent to Write().
type spinnerUpdater struct {
    s *yacspin.Spinner
    // The base message you want to write next to the spinner.
    base string
    // How many net lines of output from git are there,
    // taking control terminal codes into account?
    lines int
    // Raw output from git so far.
    output string 
}

// Terminal control code to move the cursor up one line.
const moveUp = "\033[1A"

func (su *spinnerUpdater) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    su.output += string(b)

    // Add one line for each newline we see, but subtract one
    // for each "move cursor up" control sequence.
    su.lines += strings.Count(string(b), "\n")
    su.lines -= strings.Count(string(b), moveUp)

    // Tack on some control codes to the end of the message to move
    // the cursor back up to the starting line because that's where
    // the spinner expects the cursor to be when it outputs an update.
    move := strings.Repeat(moveUp, su.lines + 1)
    su.s.Message(fmt.Sprintf("%s\n%s%s", su.base, su.output, move))

    return len(b), nil
}
```

You can then pass this into the git operation as the `Progress` value where updates will be written:

```golang
func cloneWithSpinner(target, url string) error {
    cfg := yacspin.Config{
        Frequency:     100 * time.Millisecond,
        CharSet:       yacspin.CharSets[59],
        Message: "Cloning repository",
        StopCharacter: "✓",
        StopMessage: "Done cloning repository",
        StopColors:    []string{"fgGreen"},
        StopFailCharacter: "✗",
        StopFailMessage: "Error cloning repository",
        StopFailColors: []string{"fgRed"},
    }
    spinner, err := yacspin.New(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := spinner.Start(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    updater := &spinnerUpdater{s: spinner, base: cfg.Message}
    _, err = git.PlainClone(target, false, &git.CloneOptions{
        URL:      url,
        Progress: updater,
    })
    if err != nil {
        spinner.StopFail()
    } else {
        spinner.Stop()
    }
    // Print one more time to get the cursor down to where it's supposed to be.
    fmt.Print(updater.output)
    return err
}
```

The settings in the `yacspin.Config` can be changed to whatever you want; I just put some in as an example.

Note that this code makes a key assumption about how the git operation writes output: it assumes that it only ever moves the terminal cursor up one line at a time. This seems to hold in practice, but I doubt that it's guaranteed by the git code.

If you want to make something that works *in general* for this sort of task where you want to write something below a spinner, you probably are going to end up having to emulate terminal behavior more extensively.